# Select model in OpenTX from PC through USB connection

Tags: opentx

My question is if it could be possible to change and select models on a transmitter with OpenTX, by typing the model number into the PC. It doesn't matter if it is done via USB or MAVlink connection.

I know that by adding code to the source, it can be enabled the option of sending commands to the transmitter from the PC (Refer to [Control opentx transmitter from pc?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/control-opentx-transmitter-from-pc))

Regards