# Control drone from PC

Tags: ardupilot, autonomous, opentx

I’m a programmer and novice in 'copters.  I want to control my handmade drone from PC. (Use Python script to change yaw, roll, and pitch in real-time as if it can be controller using transmitter’s joystick)

I have a Flysky FS i6 transmitter and receiver. APM 2.8 - FC

I found a [question about controlling transmitter with opentx from pc](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/control-opentx-transmitter-from-pc)  but it hasn’t updated for a long time.

What receiver and transmitter (and maybe flight controller) should I use for real-time drone control using scripts.(Not just joysticks on the transmitter)

Please give me some links to research.

There are many drone systems in agriculture sphere, but I don’t think all these drones are controlled manually by human via joystick

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot put the autopilot system on the drone (with an Arduino or something)? If the PC is directly manipulating the stick inputs then the drone will need a way to be constantly sending back its angle/position/velocity information to the PC, so that the Python code can determine what inputs need to be made to achieve the desired angle/position/velocity. The way other autopilot systems like Ardupilot have implemented this is to have an autopilot on the drone that receives waypoint/target information and follows it.

Comment: @ThatCoolCoder I've stumbled across this question as someone who is using OpenTX to control a robot. In my use case, I don't want an autopilot-type system with waypoints - I want to control what the robot does from a computer that has external sensor data that's too dense to send to the robot over the air. I don't necessarily need direct control, and I can put a microcontroller on the robot, but I do have values on a PC that need to be used by the robot.

Comment: @cdgraham it's hard to give much help without more information about your problem, but if you need to do processing outside of the robot, I would consider controlling the robot over WiFi (or a custom control link if that's not available), as opposed to off-the-shelf RC stuff.